# How to setup subscriptions in a dynamic array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm in the early stages of learning Angular and am trying to get my head around RxJS, Observable etc. Likely I've got issues with both syntax and concepts.

So here I have a service `incidentService` which gets an array of incidents and displays them on the page. If the `incident.requirementMet` property is `true` then I want the `incident.resolved` property to update on a timer for each incident in the list. When navigating to another view I want to kill off all the subscriptions.

Here's what I've attempted so far. Things have gone wrong around the `setIncidentSubscriptons()` and `postIncident()` method.

Angular v8.2
rxjs v6.4

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription, Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { IncidentService } from '../services/incident.service';
import { Incident } from '../models/incident';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-incident',
  templateUrl: './incident.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./incident.component.scss']
})
export class IncidentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private incidentSubscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  incidents: Incident[];

  constructor(private incidentService: IncidentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getIncidents();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.incidentSubscriptions.forEach(subscription => subscription.unsubscribe());
  }

  getIncidents(): void {
    this.incidentService.getIncidents()
      .subscribe((incidents) => {
        this.incidents = incidents;
        this.setIncidentSubscriptons();
      });
  }

  setIncidentSubscriptons(): void {
    let timerDelay = 1000;

    for (const i in this.incidents) {
      if (this.incidents[i].requirementMet) {
        timerDelay += 2000;

        this.incidentSubscriptions.push(
          timer(1)
          .subscribe(
            () => { this.postIncident(this.incidents[i], timerDelay); }
          )
        );
      }
    }
  }

  postIncident(incident: Incident, timerDelay: number) {
    if (incident.resolved < 100) {
      setTimeout(() => {

        incident.resolved += 1;
        this.incidentService.updateIncident(incident).subscribe(() => {
          this.postIncident(incident, timerDelay);
        });

      }, timerDelay);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? Do you want the `timer` to fire periodically? Then you need a second argument ([take a look here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html)). How is the incident list in the `IncidentService` manipulated? For me it looks like there are to much subscriptions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to do all your logic with RxJS operators and construct an Observable that will do all your tasks this way. Only subscribe once to the final Observable.

I assumed that `this.incidentService.updateIncident(incident)` only emits once and then completes and that the emitted value isn't used.

```js
import { timer, forkJoin, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, concatMap, switchMap, takeUntil, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

private onDestroy$ = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.getAndUpdateIncidents().subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.onDestroy$.next();
  this.onDestroy$.complete();
}

getAndUpdateIncidents(): Observable<any[]> { // 'any' is whatever this.incidentService.updateIncident(incident) returns
  return this.incidentService.getIncidents().pipe(
    tap(incidents => this.incidents = incidents), // assign the returned incidents
    switchMap(incidents => this.updateIncidents(incidents)), // switch to an Observable that updates the incidents
    takeUntil(this.onDestroy$) // unsubscribe on destroy
  )
}

updateIncidents(incidents: Incident[]): Observable<any[]> {
  let timerDelay = 1000;
  return forkJoin(incidents // use forkJoin to execute an array of Observables parallely
    .filter(incident => incident.requirementMet) // only take incidents who meet the requirement
    .map(incident => { // map to an Observable that periodically updates the incident
      timerDelay += 2000;
      timer(0, timerDelay).pipe( // timer will emit numbers with a given delay
        take(100), // only take 100 numbers
        concatMap(_ => { // map to the Observable that updates the incident, 
          // concatMap ensures that the next update will only be executed when the previous completed
          incident.resolved += 1;
          return this.incidentService.updateIncident(incident);
        })
      )
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for this explanation and example it's just what I needed!